# How to get additional row data to stay with row when linked to another spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets, importrange

I have data in columns A:C of Spreadsheet 1 being pulled from Spreadsheet 2 via =importrange. Columns D:Z of Spreadsheet 1 is just text related to the imported data:

Spreadsheet 1 pulls start/end dates & event name from Spreadsheet 2. In column D:Z, I enter various notes about that event.

If I enter a new row between two existing rows on Spreadsheet 2, it adds it to Spreadsheet 1, but columns D:Z do not stick with the event. They remain in the same place they were before the row was added.

Is there a way to make the notes stay with that event on Spreadsheet 1 even if I add new data to Spreadsheet 2 between existing data?

Comment: Welcome to [Web Applications Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are describing how formula results get misaligned with manually entered data. There is no turn-key solution to work around the issue. Lance has given a thorough [treatment of the row misalignment issue](https://support.google.com/docs/thread/95901649) and how it can be dealt with in some cases.